# $scope is undefined inside $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c#-4.0

My angular code

```js
angular.module('MyApp').
controller('ProductController', function ($scope, DropDownService) {
    $scope.Product = {};
    $scope.ProductCategoryList = null;
    DropDownService.GetCategory().then(function (d)
    {
        $scope.ProductCategoryList = d.data;
    });
}).
factory('DropDownService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetCategory = function() {
        return $http.get('/Product/GetAllCategory');
    };
    return fac;
});
```

my server side

```js
public JsonResult GetAllCategory()
        {
            
            //List<tblCategory> categories = new List<tblCategory>();
            try
            {
                using(CurtainHomesDBEntities  dc = new CurtainHomesDBEntities())
                {
                     var categories = dc.tblCategory.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.CatagoryName }).ToList();
                     return Json(new { data = categories, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex);
            }
        }
```

I did same way many times. but throwing js error `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined` when assigning value to `$scope.ProductCategoryList` after `$http` request. What is the problem here? I tried many way but couldn't find out.

Even I tried in this way

```js
angular.module('MyApp').
controller('ProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Product = {};
    $scope.LoadCategory = function () {
        $scope.categoryList = null;

        $http.get('/Product/GetAllCategory/')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.categoryList = data.data;
        })
        .error(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            toastr.error(XMLHttpRequest + ": " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown, 'Error!!!');
        })
    };
});
```

Same problem. $scope is not defined

Comment: You didn't inject the service.

Comment: After uploading the code I found it and uploaded the correct code. problem is same even now. I tried many ways. Without using service and directly calling get. problem is similar

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject `$scope` as well as your `service`

```
angularModule.controller("ProductController", ["$scope","$http", 'DropDownService', function ($scope, $http, DropDownService) {
    $scope.Product = {};
    $scope.ProductCategoryList = null;
    DropDownService.GetCategory().then(function (d)
    {
        $scope.ProductCategoryList = d.data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: service added previously. how to actually inject $scope? like factory('DropDownService', function ($http,$scope). But it is occurring injector error.

Comment: Why do we need to inject $http? Isnt it already injected in the service?

Comment: @ImabAsghar, if the product is getting all data from service only, then it wont be needed, it controller is performing some action in its own in that case it will need.

Comment: But in your code I dont think controller is performing any action that requires $http to be injected.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the service in your controller,

```
  angularModule.controller("ProductController", ['$scope','$http', 'DropDownService', function ($scope, $http, DropDownService) {    
        $scope.Product = {};
        $scope.ProductCategoryList = null;
        DropDownService.GetCategory().then(function (d)
        {
            $scope.ProductCategoryList = d.data;
        });
    })
```

Comment: Why do we need to inject $http? Isnt it already injected in the service?

Comment: @ImabAsghar Actually not needed